# multi-factor login with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Has anyone created or read an article on creating a multi-factor login system for asp.net? The ideas would to be a have a security question after the login to validate the user. The security question would be something they would generate. Kinda similiar to the way some online banks do it.

Comment: No worries..im actually surprised it wasn't easier to find any articles or information on this type of login. Always good to hear others point of view because working solo you often don't push yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you wouldn't be able to use the built-in login controls for ASP.NET but rolling your own is easy enough.  You would simply delay the call to                     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...); until after the second page.

Comment: so the loginurl would be the first login page...if passed sent to the second page..then set the formsauth cookie once the second piece is validated?

Comment: Right - the first page collects the User ID, for example.  If a matching ID is found in the database, then a redirect to the second page is sent.  On the second page, the user will enter their password (identify a picture, etc.).  Assuming the password matches, you'll SetAuthCookie.

Comment: Got it. I would just need to set some session variable that the user passed the first step so if someone tries to bypass the login process it they would be redirected to the second login page or to a error page.

Comment: Yes - that is right...you must not count on an argument passed in the URL!  Anyone arriving without the appropriate session variable set would be redirected back to the signin page.

Comment: Hey Mark and others, If you have a chance take a look at this little test project. I have it working but wouldn't mind any extra pair of eyes to see if it looks ok. http://is.gd/rekn

Comment: i think i might have cleaned the code up a bit to much. On the validatelogin Page_Load it should look like this:

Comment: if (!MySess.Current.IsFirstStepValidated)
                    FormsAuth.RedirToLoginPage();
                else
                    if (MySess.Current.IsFirstStepValidate)
                        if (MySess.Current.IsSecondStepValidate)
                            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

Comment: Chopps - if you are on the second page, you'll just have the "if (!..IsFirstStepValidated) Response.Redirect(..); in the PageLoad. Then in the button handler where they enter the password, you'll redirect to the login destination. I don't think you'll even need to declare a session var for step 2.

Comment: your right...the user at that point will be authenticated so I can use that to check if need be.